# Can't upload APK due to "The file is invalid: ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found"

Tags: android, upload, android-manifest, apk

**First**: I'm not help vampire)  I'm fighting with this issue for two days and I'm desperate to find solution. I've googled for the solution all over the inet and none is my case - this is the final stage and it feels hopeless.

*To be clear*: messing with `AndroidManifest.xml` doesn't help (no empty or unclosed tags etc). Nor app size issue (official limit is 4GB). Nor browser\system cause tried in FF, Chrome, IE 9 , Win 7, MacOSX SL 10.6.4, from my PC and from remote Server with Win2008 - same error.

**Second** - I extracted the `AndroidManifest.xml` from the APK file I submitted successfully (one with 13MB size) and extracted `AndroidManifest.xml` from the APK I'm trying to submit (yes, it's there! the size of this APK is 50MB) both with same apktool v 1.4.1. I compared the `AndroidManifest.xml` files with tortoise Diff - and the only difference between them is presence of `android:targetSdkVersion="8"` attribute in unuploadable APK and of course package name (diff only in  .sub of `com.mycompany.app.vers.sub` - so i guess not a reason for this googlemare I'm having on ).

No way to give up on `android:targetSdkVersion="8"` - cause it can't be a reason for the error too.

Both APK were created with File -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application with same keystore and key. I uploaded another app - third one with same `AndroidManifest.xml` as first one (without `android:targetSdkVersion="8"`) but also of small size - 9MB, nothing bigger works((!

Help - I hate google and android now, almost :)

Comment: Are they in the same directory? And that different in package names can be the problem. Is the AndroidManifest.xml targeting the same package as your application's package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of an Android app to be uploaded to Android Market is 50MB. If you're even one byte over this, I believe that the upload will fail. See [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-market-client-update.html) for reference.

Comment: It was announced at Google IO that the size limit will be increased significantly (to 4GB) but I'm not sure when this will happen.

Comment: One has to wonder about downloading apps that large to a phone. Granted, if you need the media, you need the media, but it seems like a smaller app that then downloads media in the background as needed (or anticipated) would make for a much nicer user experience.

Comment: I agree, and you're ruling out most devices released before 2011 with such a large binary. That said, I'm sure there are situations where a second installation would provide a poorer experience. The change at least brings the market in line with Apple's App Store.

Comment: Yes - seems you are both right. Regarding 4GB size limit - it was just an announcement. We implemented secondary install - i just have to turn it on back now. Misleading news + some connection issues that were giving same error for another 27MB app  - tx

Answer (score 2):

If you ran into the same problem I did with apktool, then please make sure you download the .jar file along with aapt.exe, that fixed it for me. I was running aapt.exe on an apk and got your above error, but it turns out I should have been running the apktool.bat file. The apktool.bat won't work if the .jar is not in the same directory. Get the jar file here: [Android-APKTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool1.4.1.tar.bz2)